# Selenium click by link text but text inside p tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn selenium and start working on github topics and i want to click on a particular topic without using XPATH.

Here is html code

```
<a href="/topics/3d" class="no-underline flex-1 d-flex flex-column">
        <p class="f3 lh-condensed mb-0 mt-1 Link--primary">3D</p>
        <p class="f5 color-fg-muted mb-0 mt-1">
          3D modeling is the process of virtually developing the surface and structure of a 3D object.
        </p>
      </a>
```

This is what i have tried
`driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'3D').click()`

The reason its not working is that '3D' is inside a **p** tag which is inside **a** tag

So is there a way to resolve this, i dont want to make it static .

As the goal is not to make it static, i fixed it by

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href,"topics/3d")]'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findElement(By.className())` or `findElement(By.cssSelector())`

#### className

```
findElement(By.className("f3 lh-condensed mb-0 mt-1 Link--primary"));
```

#### cssSelector

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("p[class='f3 lh-condensed mb-0 mt-1 Link--primary']"));
```

Comment: actually i was looking for a dynamic way instead of static ones